# Changing two abstract names in same document

Tags: abstract

I have a LaTeX document with two abstracts (in two different languages)

I would like to change the 'abstract' to another title.

I cannot use `\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Example}` because I need to define two different abstract names.

Can this be done somehow?

```
\usepackage{abstract}
\begin{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Example}
cdsvsdavsa
\end{abstract}
\pagebreak
\begin{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Example2}
cdsvsdavsa
\end{abstract}
```

Comment: use `\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Example} ` after the first abstract.

Comment: I tried but it did not change the name

Comment: It always helps if you supply an example code, the details depend on the class file's definition of `\abstract`. (I removed the latex3 tag as I assume your class is not using latex3 code)

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: Please make example complete documents that people can run, see my answer, also you need to put the redefinition _after_ the first abstract but _before_ (not inside) the second.

Answer (score 2):

The following example uses package `babel` to add support for different languages. The example uses `english` as main language and adds a abstract in `ngerman`. Environment `abstract` uses `\abstractname`, which is automatically redefined for different languages. Also switching the language sets the correct hyphenation patterns for the language.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}

\begin{document}
  \begin{abstract}
    Abstract in English.
  \end{abstract}

  \begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman}
    \begin{abstract}
      Zusammenfassung in deutscher Sprache.
    \end{abstract}
  \end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abstract}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Example}
\begin{abstract}
cdsvsdavsa
\end{abstract}
\pagebreak
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Example2}
\begin{abstract}
cdsvsdavsa
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```